# Why is Jquery $ showing undefined in webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the following code in my index.js file in src folder:

```js
import './styles/main.scss';
import $ from 'jquery';

//Smooth scroll
$(".navbar a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      const hash = this.hash;
      $("html, body").animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top,
        },
        800
      );
    }
  });
```

However when I build the project I get this error:

```js
ERROR in ./src/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '[url]\src'
     @ ./src/index.js 2:0-23 4:0-1 9:4-5 10:17-18
     @ ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html
```

I cant figure out what is causing this issue. I followed the webpack documentation about configuring externals and i still get this error. If you look in my config file, you will see I have externals configured. This is my webpack configuration file:

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmLWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCSSExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmLWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
    }),
    new MiniCSSExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
  ],
  externals: {
    jquery: "jQuery",
  },
};
```

[image: Package.json]

Answer (score 0):

replace `import $ from 'jquery';`

with

`jQuery = $ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Comment: It still says Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery'

Comment: so install it with npm, run `npm install jquery --save`

Comment: Okay did that and its now saying window is not defined

Comment: try remove window.jQuery and check it again